# Why node.js program doesn't exit after pausing stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading [Pro Node.js for Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430258608) and there's the following passage there:

> In addition to unpausing the stdin stream, resume() prevents an
>   application from terminating, as it will be in a state of waiting for
>   input. However, stdin **can be paused again**, using the pause() method,
>   **to allow the program to exit**.

I've tried the following snippet from the book:

```
process.stdin.once("data", function (data) {
    const response = data.toString();
    console.log("You said your name is " + response);
    process.stdin.pause();
});
console.log("What is your name?");
process.stdin.resume();
```

But after printing out the input and pausing the stdin stream the program still doesn't exit. Why?

Comment: Which book is that? Please cite.

Comment: @Bergi, it's [Pro Node.js for Developers](https://www.amazon.com/Pro-Node-js-Developers-Colin-Ihrig/dp/1430258608)

Comment: Hello, how did you start node script?

Comment: @DenisLisitskiy, I started it using WebStorm `run` configuration. I just tried to start it using `terminal` and the process exited. Thanks for the hint. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Maximus, sure, already posted as an Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start script using terminal, aka

```
node script.js
```

And it will be work as expected.

Comment: just mention that starting it from WebStorm doesn't exit